# Postgresql Error in psql command not found in zsh mac

Tags: postgresql, zsh, psql

I have installed postgresql on my mac!

- However when I run the command "psql" it says:

```
zsh: command not found: psql
```

- I have located the location of my psql command (with other all postgres commands + pgadmin) and it is in /Users/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin
- when I do echo $PATH I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

- Now what do I do to run psql without any error?

Comment: Check PATH. Use `which psql` to locate it and add/modify PATH. How did you install it?

Comment: @kometen when I run "which psql" it says: "psql not found"... also I installed it through postgresql site with pgadmin. Also I added PATH in my question.. pls check

Comment: Notice that the location of `psql` is not on the `PATH`. You will have to modify your path to include it

Comment: Or symlink the bins into `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @FredStark oh okay, thanks.. then should I add "export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin:$PATH" in my bash_profile?

Comment: yes, but in your `.zshrc` since you're not using bash

Comment: how do I add it in my .zshrc ? also how do I know if I have one or not? If I dont have it.. how can I create one? @FredStark

Comment: Open .zshrc in an editor and the line above you mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/Users/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin` is not in your "path"

Easy solution would be to create a symbolic link for `psql` in `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
ln -s /Users/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql
```

Otherwise you can edit your profile file and extend your path to `/Users/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin`

Comment: Worked perfectly, my psql path was `/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql`

Answer (score 3):

#### What i did to make it work:

1. I didn't have a `.zshrc` file and created one (peeped here [link](https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac))

   - Steps for creation:

     - Open Terminal
     - Type `touch ~/.zshrc` to create the respective file. (`touch` command will create the `.zshrc` in your current directory but it will be hidden)
     - Hit `Return`
   - To view/open `~/.zshrc` you can do either of two things:

     - Open Finder > Press `Cmd`+`Shift`+`.` (and you will see hidden files) 
        my path to the file: Macintosh HD > Users > anatolii => .zshrc

     Or:

     - Open Terminal > and type: `open ~/.zshrc`
2. Editing `.zshrc`

   - Open `.zshrc` in editor and pasted this line: 
     export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and a simple solution is to restart the terminal.
It gives an opportunity for terminal to reload Postgres.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What I did was first locate the "psql" command, which for me was in
`"/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/bin"`
other commands were their as well.
Then I opened up `".zshrc"` in `iterm2`, but im sure any terminal works.
I then pasted this line

```
# Postgres
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/bin:$PATH
```

Do not forget to save the file.
After, make sure it is up and running using your terminal of choice by typing "psql".