# How can I enable psql in the Terminal in Mac OSX?

Tags: postgresql, terminal, path

I am a medical researcher seeking to use the [MIMIC database](https://physionet.org/content/mimiciv/2.2/hosp/#files-panel). To set this up on my computer I am following [these instructions](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/main/mimic-iv/buildmimic/postgres/README.md). The process describes cloning a repo and then setting up a PostgreSQL database locally. I have `Postgre 16.1` installed via Homebrew. I have `pgadmin` installed. I have cloned the repo.

My issue comes at this step:

> Change to the mimic-iv/buildmimic/postgres/ directory. Create the schemas and tables with the following psql command. This will delete any data present in the schemas.

```
psql -f create.sql
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

```
zsh: command not found: psql
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Postgre a number of times, trying a standalone installer and Homebrew to try and get the command line tools installed. That hasn't worked.

I checked [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926868/postgresql-error-in-psql-command-not-found-in-zsh-mac) to the same issue and noticed references to PATH. I'm a simple medic and amateur machine learner and it leaves me fairly confused. I investigated mine and seem to have an absolute mess that has accrued over time:

```
/Users/<MY_NAME>/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/<MY_NAME>/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Components:/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/16/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/16/bin
```

Quite honestly I'm not sure where to even go from here, and would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the direction of being able to make the aforementioned solution work or how on earth I tidy up the PATH or tell me even if I need to?

**Using PostgreSQL 16.1 on Macbook Air M1, OSX Sonoma 14.0**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on root user run `sudo find / -name pg_config`. This terminal utility is usually inside the `bin` folder. The output of the command might give you something like this, `usr/bin/pg_config` `usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config`. Then from there we can set path like this, `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin`. Run `psql --version` to make sure psql utility is working.`psql` should work if path is set.